# Android- how to programmatically wedge a view between views in layout pre-loaded from the XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I'm developing an android app with fragments. While most of my layouts are pre-determined in the XML, I would like to programmatically insert a new view between views that were already loaded in a LinearLayout at startup.

[image]

How do I go about with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the view with the black border? Is it a LinearLayout?

Comment: +1 for including clear illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible to specify index while u dynamically add a view to a LinearLayout.

Set height of the first view as

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Set `height = wrap_content` for the second view in `XML`

Then while u are adding new View dynamically, set its `height = wrap_content` and  add it to the parent `LinearLayout` like this

```
 parentLinearLayout.addView(childView, index);     
                 //index = position where you want to insert the new view.
```

It might help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

the red View should have the default setting `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` right at the beginning. When its time to show up you can switch over to `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. I cant verify the solution right now, but it should do the trick. So in this case you are not inserting a new View but make an existing one visible.

Comment: Thank you. While it might work, I was looking for a more dynamic way of going about with this. Rahmathullah provided a way to do this programatically